# Прибор - бессуффиксный способ?

Tags: словообразование

Образовалось ли слово "прибор" бессуффиксным способом7

Answer (score 1):

Нет,в соврем. русском языке это непроизводное слово

Comment: Да. И наверное, в рамках заданного вопроса ответ достаточен. Речь явно идет о школьных нуждах.  

А вот с диахронической (вернее бы сказать "диахронистской") точки зрения - не уверен... Неужели даже такие очевидные родственники, как выбор, забор, убор, - не являются однокоренными?

Answer (score 0):

Если бы оно было образовано от глагола, то да. Для сравнения: переходить - переход

> почему бы слову "прибор" не произойти от глагола "прибрать - прибирать"?

Слова "прибор" в этом смысле не существует. Или где-то говорят: "Я делаю прибор помещения" ?

Comment: Непонятно, почему бы слову "прибор" не произойти от глагола "прибрать - прибирать"?

Comment: >Если бы оно было образовано от глагола, то да.  
  
А иначе - нет? Что это за условие?